# "ValueError: multiclass format is not supported" roc_auc_score

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, logistic-regression, countvectorizer

I have been trying to do sentiment analysis on twitter. I am kinda new at coding so I am going paralel with an tutorial. So my csv file basically have two columns. One of them is tweets and the other is sentiments.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
y = train_tweets.Sentiment
X= train_tweets.Tweets
train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(encoding='iso-8859-9').fit(train_X)
train_X_cv = cv.transform(train_X)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=FutureWarning)
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(train_X_cv, train_y)

from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
prediction = model.predict(cv.transform(val_X))
print('AUC: ', roc_auc_score(val_y, prediction))
```

My code looks like this. When I try to run this code I get "ValueError: multiclass format is not supported" this error. You have any idea what I should do?

Thank you!

Comment: ROC analysis is a binary metric (ie. only two classes to get sensitivity and specificity). Sentiment analysis is not a binary problem therefore this library cannot be used. Change your results analysis to something that supports multiclass analysis or code your own AUC ROC function.